# Presentations of algebraic stacks that are surjective on k points

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks

Let $\mathfrak X$  be an algebraic stack defined over a finite field $k$. Is the following known: there exists a presentation $X \to \mathfrak X$ such that

(*) for any finite extension $F/k$, the natural map $X(F)\to ob(\mathfrak X(F))$ is essentially surjective?

More generally, if $\mathfrak X$ is defined over a ring $R$, can one choose a presentation $X \to \mathfrak X$ such that (*) will be satisfied for any finite field $k$ over $R$?

We think we have an argument, and we are looking to replace it by a reference.

Comment: There is a statement in Laumon and Moret-Bailly near where they talk about the local structure of a stack and residual gerbes.  I will try to look up the precise reference.

Comment: The two most relevant results in Laumon and Moret-Bailly are Theorem 6.5, p. 50, and Theoreme 11.5, p. 95.